# Density function of $Z = X / (X+Y)$

Tags: statistics

Let $X,Y$ be random continuous variables. What is the pdf of $Z=X/ (X+Y)$?

What I tried is reordering $$Z=\frac{X}{X+Y}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{Y}{X}}$$ and then trying to find out the pdf of $W=Y/X$.

My guess is that then $f_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(wx)dx$ but I do not know how to prove this.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=\frac X{X+Y}$ and $W=X+Y$, from which it follows that $X=ZW$ and $Y=W(1-Z)$.

Then the joint density of $Z$ and $W$ is

$$f_{Z,W}(z,w)=f_{X,Y}(zw,w(1-z))\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\end{bmatrix}\right|=f_{X,Y}(zw,w(1-z))w$$

and the density of $Z$ is obtained by integrating the joint density over the support of $W$,

$$f_Z(z)=\int_{\mathrm{supp}W}f_{Z,W}(z,w)\,\mathrm dw$$